# Can I make my padx and pady in place() [In python GUI]

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I was trying to use padx and pady in place() in Python tkinter GUI

something I tried :
I want to know that how can I use padx and pady in place() in this way:

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
app.geometry("433x255")
border = Frame(background = "red")
aboutme = Label(border, text = "welcome to my tkinter GUI").place(padx=1, pady=1)
border.place()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `padx` and `pady` are not supported in `.place()`.  What is the point of `padx` and `pady` for `.place()`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use padx and pady configurations on place.
Here is full list of what you can use.
https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/place.htm#M6